# How to pass select option value to inside jsp div?

Tags: javascript

data read here

```
<%
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost";
    String dbName = null;
    String TbName = null;
    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";
    Connection con = null;
    Connection conn1 = null;
    Connection conn2 = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    DatabaseMetaData dbmd1 = null;

    Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();

    conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    Statement stt = conn1.createStatement();
    ResultSet res1 = null;
    ResultSet res2 = null;
    ResultSet res3 = null;
    //ResultSet res4 = stt.executeQuery("SELECT id,facebook_id,name FROM profile where id <=10");

    DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn1.getMetaData();
    ResultSet ctlgs = dbmd.getCatalogs();
%>
<script>
    var val = "null";
    function dbname(db_type) {

        val = db_type;
        //document.write(val);

        document.getElementById('db_type1').style.display = 'block';

    }
</script>

<script>
    var name = "Gautam";
    //document.write(val);
</script>

<center>
    <h1>Face book Database Element</h1>

        <select  name="selurl" onchange="dbname(this.value)">
            <%
                while (ctlgs.next()) {

                    dbName = ctlgs.getString(1);
            %>
            <option value="<%=dbName%>"><%=dbName%> </option>
            <%
                }

            %>

        </select> 

</center>


<center>

    <select onchange="dbname(this.value)">
        <option name="choice1" value="red">red</option>
        <option name="choice2" value="blue">blue</option>

    </select>

    <div id="db_type1" style="display: none;">

        <%String s = request.getParameter("val");

        System.out.print(url+"/"+s);
        conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url+"/"+s,user,pass);
      //System.out.print(url+"/"+s);
        Statement stmt = conn2.createStatement();
        dbmd1 = conn2.getMetaData();


                String[] types = {"TABLE"};
            res1 = dbmd.getTables(null, null, "%", types);


        %>

    <select id="selectB" name="selu">
    <%  while (res1.next()) {

            TbName = res1.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            System.out.print(TbName);
        %>  
        <option value="<%=TbName%>"><%=TbName%> </option>   
    <%  }
    %>
```

```
      <select onchange="dbname(this.value)">
      <%String locate=request.getParameter("name"); %>
        <option value="<%=locate%>"><%=locate%> </option>   
        <option name="choice1" value="red">red</option>
        <option name="choice2" value="blue">blue</option>

     </select>

    </div>

    <div id="db_type" style="display: none;">
        <p>You want BLUE</p>
    </div>

</center>
```

here value pass null means conn2 database name is null